# When using pagination, how can I tell Google to prefer indexing the first page?

Tags: seo, google, google-index, pagination

I have a website for searching jobs. When user searching for some term, multiple results are displayed, and there is a pagination to browse these results (e.g. "page1", "page2", etc).

I would expect, that when potential user search Google for term found on my site, first results page from my site will be displayed in Google results. However, sometimes I see that pages like "page3" are displayed instead. This not looks good.

Why Google decides to show page number 3 instead of first page? Is there any way to "tell" it to always prioritize first page?

Comment: You shouldn't let Google crawl and index your search results at all.   Google considers it bad user experience when users click off the Google search results only to find they landed on another site's search results.   Google sometimes penalizes sites that allow their search results to be crawled and indexed.  See https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/

Comment: I agree, don't index your search result pages. However, if it was e.g. a product category spanning multiple pages you can use paginated pages with rel="prev" and "next". That would help search engines understand your page structure and their importance.